# Strapi Graphql query with filtering/conditional rendering

Tags: graphql, strapi

In my Strapi project, i'm trying to write a Graphql query that filters posts by an array of tags.
The post has to belong to all tags of the given array.
E.g. the post below would not meet the condition if given array is [1,2,3] but would pass the condition if array is [3,5].

Any help would be much appreciated

Example Post:

```
 {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "Lorem Iopsum",       
      "created_at": "2021-02-19T22:53:19.204Z",
      "tags": [
        {
          "id": "3",
          "tag": "Porte De Gentily"
        },
        {
          "id": "5",
          "tag": "Bridges"
        },  
        {
          "id": "6",
          "tag": "Towers"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I was trying something like:

```
query {
 posts( where: {tags: {id_contains: [3,1]}}) {
    title
    tags{id},
    created_at
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like this

```
query($ids:[ID]) {
 posts( where: {tags: {id:$ids}}) {
    title
    tags{id},
    created_at
  }
}
```

And pass your ids as a query variable:

```
{
  "ids": [1,5] 
}
```